# Enterprise portal page on Dynamics AX 2012

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I am using Dynamics AX 2012 Hyper-V image and Dynamics AX client works perfectly.
But my EP home page is not coming up. It gives an error like below.

> Message: An unhandled error has occurred. To view details about this
>   error, enable debugging in the web.config file or view the Windows
>   event logs.

URL i am using is `http://sharepoint/sites/DynamicsAx/default.aspx`

I also modified the Hosts file at C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc by adding these 2 lines.

> ```
>         127.0.0.1              Sharepoint
>         127.0.0.1              dynamicsax.contoso.com
> ```

I restarted the App pool and web site in the IIS. Event Viewer is event less.
What else can i do? help!!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to modify the web.config in order to display the entire error and callstack. You could also try use this little solution that makes it a bit more easy to turn off and on debugging: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bD6NbVna_w4